# Grade Report Card Using Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

[image: I am trying to achieve this output print display]So I am trying to read a .txt file and I am unable to read it. Can you guys tell me what my mistake is?It keeps on giving error :

```
  fn, ln, id, itp = inFile.readline().split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

The Data in the text file is as follows:
3 345
Lisa Miller 890238 Y 4
Mathematics MTH345 4 A
Physics PHY357 3 B
ComputerSci CSC478 3 B
History HIS356 3 A
Tom White 123456 N 3
Calculus MTH324 3 C
ComputerSci CSC141 3 B
French FRN254 3 A
Mohamed Radi 975432 Y 4
Algebra MTH156 3 A
English ENG457 4 A
Biology BIO187 3 B
Spanich SPN657 3 A

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
> fileName = open("stData.txt", 'r')
> with fileName as inFile:
> Line = inFile.readline()
> Line = Line.split()
> n = int(Line[0]) 
> p = int(Line[1])
> print(n)
> print(p)
> st = [Student() for _ in range(n)]
> for i in range(n):
> fn, ln, id, itp = inFile.readline().split()
> ns = int(inFile.readline())
>
> st[i].setN(ns)
> st[i].setName(f"{fn} {ln}")
> st[i].setId(id)
> st[i].setIsTutionPaid(itp)
> st[i].tutionRate(p)
>
> for j in range(ns):
> a, b, cdt, grd = inFile.readline().split()
> st[i].addStudent(a, b, int(cdt), grd)
>
> print("Number of students:", n, "and tution rate $", p, "per credit hour")
> for i in range(n):
> st[i].print()
> print()
> ```

Edit :
I played around with the code a removed the error but not I don't get any errors, my program is only printing out the last STUDENT INFO. ANY TAKE ON HOW CAN I SOLVE THIS? I have added my updated version as well

> 

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
>     inFile= open("stData.txt", 'r')
>     with inFile as inFile:
>         line = inFile.readline().split()
>         numStd = int(line[0]) 
>         Tuition_Rate = int(line[1]) 
>         print(numStd , Tuition_Rate)
> 
>         Std = [Student() for i in range(numStd)] 
>         for i in range(numStd):
>             Line2 = inFile.readline().split() 
>             First_Name = Line2[0]
>             ID = Line2[1]
>             isTutionPaid = Line2[2] 
>             noOf_Subjects = int(Line2[3]) 
>             Std[i].setN(noOf_Subjects) 
>             Std[i].setName(f"{First_Name}")
>             Std[i].setId(ID)
>             Std[i].setIsTutionPaid(isTutionPaid)
>             Std[i].tutionRate(Tuition_Rate) 
>             for j in range (noOf_Subjects) : 
>                 Line3 = inFile.readline().split()  
>                 Course_Name = Line3[0]
>                 Course_Number = Line3[1]
>                 Credit_Hours = Line3[2] 
>                 Grade = Line3[3]   
>                 Std[i].addStudent(Course_Name, Course_Number, int(Credit_Hours), Grade)
>     print("Number of students:", numStd, "and Tuition Rate $", Tuition_Rate, "per credit hour")
>     for k in range (numStd) : 
>         Std[i].print() 
>         print()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that there are more than 4 elements in the array returned by split.

The problem might be this line: `Tom White 123456 N 3`

```
>>> s = "Tom White 123456 N 3"
>>> line = s.split()
>>> line
['Tom', 'White', '123456', 'N', '3']
```

You see, it has length 5.

### Tips :)

These kinds of problems come up all the time. It's useful to have some techniques for debugging them. One easy option is to use print statements:

The goal would be to figure out exactly what line is causing problems. When your code fails, you want it to fail in the most informative way possible.

```
# fn, ln, id, itp = inFile.readline().split()  # remove this line

# this does the same thing: 

line = inFile.readline().split()
print(line)
fn, ln, id, itp = line
```

You'll see exactly what is going wrong, on what line.

Of course, `print` debugging isn't the most powerful or production-ready tool in the toolbox, but it is useful.

You can also look into the buildin Python debugger - `breakpoint()` is your friend.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did remove the error but the code is unable to print/display the All three students information. I am only getting the last student information

Comment: @SyedQasimQamarAbbasJafri your code would be much easier to read if you used a standard naming convention. Or at least something consistent. 

I would have the same general advice as before, try to use breakpoints or print statements to see the exact values of your variables at different points. You have made an incorrect assumption somewhere.

Comment: Yes Ma'am I did make an incorrect assumption. I used your advice to sort out the problem. Thank you.